# Methods of eliminating ambiguity in CFG

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars, ambiguity

I am looking for all possible ways to find and eliminate ambiguity in CF grammar. Please share your knowledge or opinion (preferably you will indicate the literature so that I can familiarize myself).I know that it is impossible to check whether the grammar is ambiguous and there is no 100% solution, but I need to consider all existing ways that can partially remove ambiguity.
I know that ambiguity can generate chain rules. I also know that some constructions, for example S->SaS, generate ambiguity.
P.S. sorry for my English. I am not a native speaker.

Comment: To check if a given grammar is ambiguous or not is an undecidable problem.

Comment: I don't need a 100% solution to the problem. I need to find out all possible ways to determine that it is (or may be) ambiguous and, if possible, eliminate it.

Comment: There is no list of all possible ways.  For any list of possible ways, it is always possible to find another way that covers another ambiguous grammar not covered by any in the prior list.

Comment: can you tell me the ways that you know?T hat's all I'm asking.